# Springboot SseEmitter timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

Trying to execute the following springboot SSE code:

```
@Controller
public class DataActivityController {
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value="/sse/mvc/emitter")
    public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> handleRequest () {

        final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        service.execute(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                try {
                    emitter.send(i + " - ", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    emitter.completeWithError(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
            emitter.complete();
        });
        return new ResponseEntity(emitter, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Then trying to connect from a webbrowser using:

```
<script>
function sendRequest(){
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/sse/mvc/emitter");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("sseDiv").innerHTML += event.data + " - ";
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("sseDiv").innerHTML =
                     "Your browser does not support server-sent events.";
    }
}
</script>
```

yields display on the browser: "timeout":null} - {"timeout":null} - {"timeout":null} - {"timeout":null} - {"timeout":null} - {"timeout":null} - {"timeout":null}.

However, no error is displayed in springboot application.

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue in your script. SSE java code seems to be fine.

```
SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(-1L);
```

Add this as your emitter initialization statement.